# Simple android password checker not working

Tags: java, android, if-statement, password-protection

I am creating a Android application and the fist activity that will open will be a password entry. For know the password has already been set in a variable with the value "admit". I have created a if statement to check what value the user has entered and then compare it to the variable, and if the values match then go to the home screen, however it keeps saying it is the wrong password. Can anybody take a look at my code and advise were i am going wrong.

```
public class Password extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    protected String password = "admin";
    String getPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_password);
        Button passwordButton = (Button) findViewById(passwordbutton);
        EditText passwordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        getPassword = (passwordInput.getText().toString());
        passwordButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (getPassword.equals(password)) {
            Intent goHome;
            goHome = new Intent(this, home.class);
            startActivity(goHome);
        } else {
             AlertDialog.Builder wrongPasswordBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            wrongPasswordBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.wrongPasswordTitle));
            wrongPasswordBuilder.setMessage(getString(R.string.wrongPasswordTryAgain));
            wrongPasswordBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
            AlertDialog dialog = wrongPasswordBuilder.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `getPassword = (passwordInput.getText().toString());` this does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

**If you write passwordInput.getText().toString() in onCreate(), it always return empty String. So write these lines in onClick(). Code is written below**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
getPassword = passwordInput.getText().toString()
if (getPassword.equals(password)) {
    Intent goHome;
    goHome = new Intent(this, home.class);
    startActivity(goHome);
} else {
     AlertDialog.Builder wrongPasswordBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    wrongPasswordBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.wrongPasswordTitle));
    wrongPasswordBuilder.setMessage(getString(R.string.wrongPasswordTryAgain));
    wrongPasswordBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = wrongPasswordBuilder.show();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place `getPassword = passwordInput.getText().toString();` within your `OnClickListener`. Right now your variable `getPassword` is being set in your `onCreate` method, so it will always be set to what your default value is for the `EditText`. Instead, you need to update the variable every time the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_password);
Button passwordButton = (Button) findViewById(passwordbutton);
EditText passwordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

passwordButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

}

```
public void onClick(View v) {
//Place the getPassword variable in the onClick method. That way it's stored everytime you click it.
getPassword = (passwordInput.getText().toString());

if (getPassword.equals(password)) {
    Intent goHome;
    goHome = new Intent(this, home.class);
    startActivity(goHome);
} else {
     AlertDialog.Builder wrongPasswordBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    wrongPasswordBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.wrongPasswordTitle));
    wrongPasswordBuilder.setMessage(getString(R.string.wrongPasswordTryAgain));
    wrongPasswordBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = wrongPasswordBuilder.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and help everyone, silly mistake once it is pointed out !